# How do I fix this runtime error (java.lang.NumberFormatException: null) when I click the button for the Action Listener?

Tags: java, null, runtime-error, jtextfield

I am using Java Ready to Program 1.4. It is saying that I haven't inputted anything in the JTextField, but I inputted the variables before clicking the button.

```
public class MortgageCalculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
private String nameText, ageText, incomeText, priceText, downPayText, interestRateText, paymentText, amortText;


public MortgageCalculator ()
{ //Frame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize (new Dimension (300, 250));
    frame.setTitle ("Mortgage Calculator");
    frame.getContentPane ().setLayout (new BorderLayout ());

    //User Information (Input) - Center Panel
    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel (new GridLayout (16, 1));
    //Personal Information
    centerPanel.add (new JLabel ("                          Personal Information"));
    centerPanel.add (new JLabel ("Full Name:"));
    JTextField nameField = new JTextField ();
    centerPanel.add (nameField);
    centerPanel.add (new JLabel ("Your Age:"));
    JTextField ageField = new JTextField ();
    centerPanel.add (ageField);
    centerPanel.add (new JLabel ("Yearly Income:"));
    JTextField incomeField = new JTextField ();
    centerPanel.add (incomeField);
    centerPanel.add (new JLabel ());
    //Mortgage Information
    centerPanel.add (new JLabel ("                          Mortgage Information"));
    centerPanel.add (new JLabel ("Price of Property:"));
    JTextField priceField = new JTextField ();
    centerPanel.add (priceField);
    centerPanel.add (new JLabel ("Down Payment:"));
    JTextField downPayField = new JTextField ();
    centerPanel.add (downPayField);
    centerPanel.add (new JLabel ("Interest Rate (%):"));
    JTextField interestRateField = new JTextField ();
    centerPanel.add (interestRateField);
    centerPanel.add (new JLabel ("Amortization Period (Years):"));
    frame.getContentPane ().add (centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //User Options (Input) - South Panel
    JPanel southPanel = new JPanel (new GridLayout (8, 3));
    //Payment Option
    southPanel.add (new JLabel ("Payment:"));
    southPanel.add (new JLabel ("Type in 1, 2 or 3"));
    southPanel.add (new JLabel ());
    southPanel.add (new JLabel ("1. Weekly"));
    southPanel.add (new JLabel ("2. Biweekly"));
    southPanel.add (new JLabel ("3. Monthly"));
    JTextField paymentField = new JTextField ();
    southPanel.add (paymentField);
    southPanel.add (new JLabel ());
    southPanel.add (new JLabel ());

    //Amortization Period Option
    southPanel.add (new JLabel ("Amortization Period:"));
    southPanel.add (new JLabel ("Type in 1, 2 or 3"));
    southPanel.add (new JLabel ());
    southPanel.add (new JLabel ("1. 20 years"));
    southPanel.add (new JLabel ("2. 25 years"));
    southPanel.add (new JLabel ("3. 30 years"));
    JTextField amortField = new JTextField ();
    southPanel.add (amortField);
    southPanel.add (new JLabel ());
    southPanel.add (new JLabel ());
    //To add a blank line in frame, added three blank JLabels because it is 3 horiontal for grid layout
    southPanel.add (new JLabel ());
    southPanel.add (new JLabel ());
    southPanel.add (new JLabel ());
    southPanel.add (new JButton ("Clear Information"));
    southPanel.add (new JLabel ());
    JButton nextButton = new JButton ("Next");
    southPanel.add (nextButton);

    frame.getContentPane ().add (southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    frame.pack ();
    frame.setVisible (true);


    nextButton.addActionListener (this);

    String nameText = nameField.getText ();
    String ageText = ageField.getText ();
    String incomeText = incomeField.getText ();
    String priceText = priceField.getText ();
    String downPayText = downPayField.getText ();
    String interestRateText = interestRateField.getText ();
    String paymentText = paymentField.getText ();
    String amortText = amortField.getText ();
}

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    MortgageCalculator mainApp = new MortgageCalculator ();
}

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
{

    //Gets the personal information from the text fields
    String name;
    int age, payment, amort;
    double income, price, downPay, interestRate;

    name = nameText;

    age = Integer.parseInt (ageText);

    income = Double.parseDouble (incomeText);
    //Gets the mortgage information from the text fields

    price = Double.parseDouble (priceText);

    downPay = Double.parseDouble (interestRateText);

    interestRate = Double.parseDouble (interestRateText);
    interestRate = interestRate/100;
    payment = Integer.parseInt (paymentText);

    amort = Integer.parseInt (amortText);

    //Output frame
    JFrame frame2 = new JFrame ();
    frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame2.setSize (new Dimension (300, 250));
    frame2.setTitle ("Mortgage Calculator");
    frame2.getContentPane ().setLayout (new BorderLayout ());

    JPanel westPanel2 = new JPanel (new GridLayout (3, 1));
    JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel ("Name: " + name);
    westPanel2.add (nameLabel);
    JLabel ageLabel = new JLabel ("Age: " + age);
    westPanel2.add (ageLabel);
    JLabel incomeLabel = new JLabel ("Yearly Income: $" + income);
    westPanel2.add (incomeLabel);
    frame2.getContentPane ().add (westPanel2, BorderLayout.WEST);

    JPanel centerPanel2 = new JPanel (new GridLayout (3, 1));
    JLabel priceLabel = new JLabel ("    Price of property: $" + price);
    centerPanel2.add (priceLabel);
    JLabel downPayLabel = new JLabel ("    Down Payment: $" + downPay);
    centerPanel2.add (downPayLabel);
    JLabel interestRateLabel = new JLabel ("    Interest Rate: " + income);
    centerPanel2.add (interestRateLabel);
    frame2.getContentPane ().add (centerPanel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    double interest, numerator, l, denominator, payPerPeriod, initialP, mortgageYearly;
    if (payment==1)
    {
        interest = 1 + interestRate / 52;
        if (amort==1)
        {
            l = Math.pow (interest, 20 * 52);
            numerator = l * interest;
            denominator = l - 1;
            initialP = price - downPay;
            payPerPeriod = (numerator / denominator) * initialP;
        }
        else if (amort==2)
        {
            l = Math.pow (interest, 25 * 52);
            numerator = l * interest;
            denominator = l - 1;
            initialP = price - downPay;
            payPerPeriod = (numerator / denominator) * initialP;
        }
        else // 3. amort30
        {
            l = Math.pow (interest, 30 * 52);
            numerator = l * interest;
            denominator = l - 1;
            initialP = price - downPay;
            payPerPeriod = (numerator / denominator) * initialP;
        }
        mortgageYearly = payPerPeriod * 52;
    }
    else if (payment == 2)
    {
        interest = 1 + interestRate / 26;
        if (amort==1)
        {
            l = Math.pow (interest, 20 * 26);
            numerator = l * interest;
            denominator = l - 1;
            initialP = price - downPay;
            payPerPeriod = (numerator / denominator) * initialP;
        }
        else if (amort==2)
        {
            l = Math.pow (interest, 25 * 26);
            numerator = l * interest;
            denominator = l - 1;
            initialP = price - downPay;
            payPerPeriod = (numerator / denominator) * initialP;
        }
        else // 3. amort30
        {
            l = Math.pow (interest, 30 * 26);
            numerator = l * interest;
            denominator = l - 1;
            initialP = price - downPay;
            payPerPeriod = (numerator / denominator) * initialP;
        }
        mortgageYearly = payPerPeriod * 26;


    }
    else //3. monthly payment  
    {
        interest = 1 + interestRate / 12;
        if (amort==1)
        {
            l = Math.pow (interest, 20 * 12);
            numerator = l * interest;
            denominator = l - 1;
            initialP = price - downPay;
            payPerPeriod = (numerator / denominator) * initialP;
        }
        else if (amort==2)
        {
            l = Math.pow (interest, 25 * 12);
            numerator = l * interest;
            denominator = l - 1;
            initialP = price - downPay;
            payPerPeriod = (numerator / denominator) * initialP;
        }
        else // 2. amort30
        {
            l = Math.pow (interest, 30 * 12);
            numerator = l * interest;
            denominator = l - 1;
            initialP = price - downPay;
            payPerPeriod = (numerator / denominator) * initialP;

        }
        mortgageYearly = payPerPeriod * 12;
    }


    JPanel eastPanel2 = new JPanel (new GridLayout (3, 1));
    JLabel payTotalLabel = new JLabel ("    Payment Total: $" + initialP);
    eastPanel2.add (priceLabel);
    JLabel payPerPeriodLabel = new JLabel ("    Payment per period: $" + payPerPeriod);
    eastPanel2.add (payPerPeriodLabel);

    frame2.getContentPane ().add (eastPanel2, BorderLayout.EAST);


    JPanel southPanel2 = new JPanel (new GridLayout (2, 1));
    double minimumIncome = mortgageYearly / 0.28;
    JLabel minimumLabel = new JLabel ("    Minimum Yearly Income: $" + minimumIncome);
    eastPanel2.add (priceLabel);

    if (minimumIncome > income)
    {
        JLabel qualifiedLabel = new JLabel ("You are not qualified for the mortgage");
               eastPanel2.add (qualifiedLabel);
    }
    else
    {
        JLabel qualifiedLabel = new JLabel ("You are qualified for the mortgage");
               eastPanel2.add (qualifiedLabel);
    }


    frame2.getContentPane ().add (eastPanel2, BorderLayout.EAST);



    frame2.pack ();
    frame2.setVisible (true);



}

}
```

Comment: In `actionPerformed` method get typed text of jtextfield: `age = Integer.parseInt (ageField.getText());` and do this for every textfield

Answer (score 0):

One (or more) of the following lines expects the numeric value to be present in the string, and obviously, you passes some non-numerical value(s) as an argument to parse method.

```
age = Integer.parseInt (ageText);

income = Double.parseDouble (incomeText);

price = Double.parseDouble (priceText);

downPay = Double.parseDouble (interestRateText);

interestRate = Double.parseDouble (interestRateText);

payment = Integer.parseInt (paymentText);

amort = Integer.parseInt (amortText);
```